# MySQL Compare row count to see which user has a row in the other table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building a survey system where

- A *client* that has many *users*
- A *user* can have multiple *surveys*.

Client A might have users [1,2,3].
Now there's a table *user_completions*, which shows which users have completed my survey.

```
users table
+----+-----------+
| id | client_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         1 |
+----+-----------+


user_completions table
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | survey_id |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 |         1 |
|       2 |         2 |
+---------+-----------+
```

**How can I (in one query) see how many users have a record in the user_completion table, grouped by survey, and only for the current client**

The desired result would look something like

```
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
| survey_id | users | num_persons_completed |
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
|         1 |     2 |         1             |
|         2 |     2 |         1             |
+-----------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample output to clarify the question further?

Comment: Have you looked at JOIN's, GROUP BY?

Comment: `Survey_id` 1 has been completed by `user_id` 1

Comment: @HarshilDoshi I added an example output.

Comment: any chance where completed is not 1?

Comment: with completed I meant as a result, the number of users that have a record in the user_completions table.

Comment: ok. And `users` column shows no of user per client? Is that correct?

Comment: the users column has the users, coupled to the client using client_id

Comment: Confusing. What's the difference between `users` and `num_persons_completed` in your case?

Comment: @Notflip You forgot to show your `client` and `survey` table. Please show those. As far as I have understood, a client has made surveys that **their** users will see. Out of those users, some have completed some surveys of their choice.

Comment: According to your own sample and desired output you seem to have made a mistake. each survey only has one user attached to them in your sample set. So outputing two either breaks logic or you mean something other than the sample data seems to indicate.

Comment: in user column, OP wants to show no of user per client_id  not no of user per survey

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing couple of table mentioning in your question but if you really have only these 2 tables than you can achieve this with following query:

```
select tmp.survey_id, count(distinct tmp.user_id) completed, 
      (select count(distinct id) from users where client_id = 1) users
from
(select t1.*, t2.*
from users t1 
join user_completions t2
on t1.id = t2.user_id
where t1.client_id = 1
)tmp
group by tmp.survey_id
```

Comment: This is generating a lot of errors.. t1, t2 tmp.survey_id all nonexisting according to sequel pro.

Comment: Aha! This seems to be working, let me verify the data. thank you!